# Getting value of input(timein) with datepicker via jquery and add value to set (timeout time)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

Good day,
I am creating a time in/timeout mechanism that sets the timeout (date and time) automatically once the user select the duration via dropdown.

here is my code:

I initialized the input box:

```
$('.time_in, .time_out').datetimepicker({
            stepping:30
        });
```

then trigger change with:

```
    $('.select_book_type').change(function(){
        var x = this.value;
        for (var i = 0; i < time_rate.length; i++) 
            {
                if(x == time_rate[i].id)
                {
                console.log(time_rate[i].rate);
                var x = $(this).closest('tr');
                x.find('.rate').val(time_rate[i].rate); //sets the rate of the room

                //this part is my problem
                var time_in = x.find('.time_in').val();
                x.find('.time_out').val(time_in+time_rate[i].duration);

                }
                else if(x==null||x==0)
                {
                    var x = $(this).closest('tr');
                    x.find('.rate').val(0);
                }
            }
        });
```

supposedly Im am trying to get the value of the input with class `.time_in` to be used as the value to be added by my `time_rate[i].duration` (eg. value = 12) but whats happening is I cant get the value of `.time_in` so it will just set the timeout value into `time_rate[i].duration` (eg.12).

[image]
[image]

What I would like to accomplish:

The timeout input box should be set into `time_in + duration = timeout` or 09/02/2015 4:30 PM + 12 = 09/03/2015 4:30AM.

Thank you and have a good day ahead.

Comment: does duration will be always in hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert both time in **milliseconds** before addition and then need to convert the sum into date string

```
var time_inMilli=new Date(time_in).getTime();
var time_outMilli = time_inMilli+(time_rate[i].duration*3600*1000);
var time_out = new Date(time_outMilli).toLocaleString();
 x.find('.time_out').val(time_out);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer sir @ankit.. does the line var time-outMilli meant to be var time_outMilli ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class='col-md-5'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date'>
            <input id='datetimepicker6' type='text' class="form-control" /> <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
```

JS

```
var MinuteToAdd = 30

$(function () {
$('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
$('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
});
$("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
$('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);        
$('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").date(e.date.add(MinuteToAdd,'m'));
});
$("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);

});
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/w2qd3oqy/1/)

Comment: thanks sir @J Santosh.. specially for emphasizing the useCurrent option.. it saved me research time :) have a good day.